# check constraint on absence of data in another table

Tags: postgresql, constraints, unique

Short version of the question: I would like to constrain data in a PostgreSQL table to zero or one records with a unique combination of two fields and no data in another table referencing it.

I have a table for forecasts (outlooks) called draft_outlooks that stores draft text that our users compose via a web app. These outlooks pertain to a region, stored in a table called outlook_areas. Here is the table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE draft_outlooks
(
    objectid                   serial PRIMARY KEY,
    guid                       varchar(38) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    outlook_area_objectid      int NOT NULL REFERENCES outlooks.outlook_areas (objectid),
    forecast_date              date NOT NULL,
    json_content               jsonb NOT NULL
)
```

When the user is finished, the outlook is published, and a record goes into a table called published_outlooks. That table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE published_outlooks
(
    objectid                   serial PRIMARY KEY,
    guid                       varchar(38) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    draft_outlook_objectid     int NOT NULL 
        REFERENCES outlooks.draft_outlooks (objectid) UNIQUE,
    forecast_date              date NOT NULL,
    [...plus various fields to hold the user-entered text...]
)
```

The draft_outlook records pertain to the outlook_area_objectid and forecast_date, but can be published multiple times in the day as the user updates them, so I can't enforce uniqueness on that. What I want to achieve is for an outlook area and forecast date combination to have no more than one ***unpublished*** draft_outlook record. So it is a combination of unique outlook_area_objectid and forecast_date, plus the ***absence*** of a corresponding record in published_outlooks.

What is the simplest way to achieve this? My organization has minimal SQL skills, so I'm trying to stick to the simplest solution, so my co-workers understand whatever it is that I set up for them. Can a check constraint look for no referencing records in another table? My research indicates that I need to either add another field to draft outlooks to use a regular check constraint or I need to use a trigger.

thanks!

Comment: A check constraint cannot reference another table - doing so will cause trouble later on, e.g. during dump/restore. A trigger is only safe from race conditions with isolation level `SERIALIZABLE`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe - I think you're right that a check constraint is not possible, or at least has some real concerns. I was thinking about just adding a boolean field to the draft_outlooks table that tracks the publish status (has this been published?). The app can update that easily. 

The problem is that they are allowed to publish multiple times per day, so I would only want to enforce uniqueness on that when it is False. Is there a way to enforce uniqueness on 3 fields, but only when one of them has a value of False?

Comment: You can add a partial unique index for this.

Comment: Thanks, @LaurenzAlbe, I think that would be a great solution if we add the publish status field to the table. 

I ended up creating a function to insert the data. It has some other logic I needed in it, so I was going to create it anyhow. I just added this check to it using a "select count(*)" statement to make sure there are no other unpublished records matching the other two fields. I raise an exception if the count is greater than 0. It's not the best solution, since users could just insert records outside my function, but we're a small team and we agreed to always use the function.

Comment: Don't forget that there is a race condition: if two sessions call the function concurrently, each won't see the effects of the other transaction yet, and the result may violate the condition.